# Android Recyclerview that extends LinearLayout to a Grid

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to create a RecyclerView (or any other view for that matter) that can have a LinearLayoutManager at first and then expand all of it to a GridLayoutManager. Something like the first part of [this.](http://www.pc-tablet.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/androidn1-1.gif)

Comment: GridLayout manager with 1 column/row is the same as LinearLayout manager. So you are doing this the wrong way, do it with GridLayoutManager with one column/row and then increase the number if you need it.

Comment: @BojanKseneman okay thanks! But how should I handle swiping to move the items in place from 1 column/row to 3/3.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.qfd0olo7a

Comment: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.v6eovsi12

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll need to write yourself.  For example, have a show list/grid icon in toolbar which triggered re-rendering of RecyclerView (using either `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager` as appropriate).  You could then have your `RecyclerView.Adapter` constructor have a flag indicating which to use (and switch between different `ViewHolder` implementations in your `onCreateViewHolder` method)

Comment: True but I don't know how handle swiping in a LayoutManager. Also I found https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/PseudoGridView.java